# Why do I need to call clearTimeout twice to reset setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I ran into a puzzle as I was trying to make a rotating banner in JavaScript following [this tutorial](https://javascript-tutor.net/index.php/lesson-28-managing-banner-ads-in-javascript/).

All the images were displayed at fixed intervals with `setTimeout`. Later I would like to add a button that allows the user to switch to the next image on the banner manually, so I thought I would use `clearTimeout` to stop the timer for the automatic switching first and then reset it after the manual switch. However, I was confused by the fact that **I had to call `clearTimeout` twice in order to stop the original timer properly** before resetting it. Calling `clearTimeout` once could not stop the timer properly. Can anybody please help explain why is that the case to me? Is there anything wrong with my code? Below is part of the code:

```
//Global Variables
var switchTimeout;
myBanner = new Array("img/chicken.jpg", "img/tiger.jpg", "img/pig.jpg");
var bannerCounter = 0;

//Called after the page is loaded
function switchBanner() {
  if (document.images) {
    bannerCounter++;
    if (bannerCounter == myBanner.length) {
      bannerCounter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("banner").src = myBanner[bannerCounter];
    switchTimeout = setTimeout("switchBanner()",3000);
  }
}

//Called when user hits the button
function manualSwitch() {
  //Why do I need to call this twice for it to work?
  clearTimeout(switchTimeout);
  clearTimeout(switchTimeout);
  if (document.images) {
    bannerCounter++;
    console.log(bannerCounter);
    if (bannerCounter == myBanner.length) {
      bannerCounter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("banner").src = myBanner[bannerCounter];
    //Reset the timer now
    switchTimeout = setTimeout("switchBanner()",3000); 
  }
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I have my doubts, that calling `clearTimeout` twice in a row like that makes any difference.

Comment: Just curious, what happened exactly when you called it once? Did it just continually run for multiple iterations? Did it just change to 1 photo and you call it 'not clearing properly'? 

Also, curious what happens when you are on the last image (myBanner[2]) and then you hit the manual progress button. You are saying if it's == to length but it could go over the length and you miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and seems to work fine with calling only once, that said, this seems to be better suited to use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`. Also reducing some unnecessary code repetition.

See example using just text instead of replacing an `img`'s `source`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner"> </div>
    <button onclick="changeAndTriggerInterval()" id="bannerSwitcher">Switch Banner</button>
    <script>
        let intervalIdentifier = 0;
        let  bannerCounter = 0;
        myBanner = new Array("img/chicken.jpg", "img/tiger.jpg", "img/pig.jpg");
        // Called when user hits the button and on initial page load
        function changeAndTriggerInterval() {
            changeBanner();
            resetBannerChanger();
        }

        function resetBannerChanger() {
            if (intervalIdentifier > 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalIdentifier);
            }
            intervalIdentifier = setInterval(changeBanner, 3000);
        }

        function changeBanner() {
            // Change before updating counter to start from index 0
            document.getElementById("banner").innerText = myBanner[bannerCounter];
            bannerCounter++;
            if (bannerCounter == myBanner.length) {
                bannerCounter = 0;
            }
        }
        window.onload = changeAndTriggerInterval;
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the setInterval() method! After reading your answer, I find that it is indeed more suitable to use setInterval() in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for commenting on this question.

I just went over the code again, and tried to write another version of it using roman numerals instead of images on jsfiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ztk0s3p5/
```

Apparently, I only need to call `clearTimeOut()` once to stop the automatic switching timer in the above version. So the problem that I encountered earlier on lies in other portions of my original code. Now I am reassured that running `clearTimeout()` should get the job done. That it didn't in my original code was due to some other faults. Thanks again!